# Migrated ASP.NET application to new server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

Recently migrated an ASP.NET application from  an old server to a new server

Both servers have the Same OS Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

IIS 7.5 on both servers

SQL Server 2008 R2

The only difference is the amount of RAM and CPU speed

I have gone the server point to point and cannot find any differences.

I had a developer look at the code and he says its not the code

On the old server the website loads fine on the new server I get an error when browsing the website via domain name

Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 error '80040e4d'

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'.

/lib/SQLHelper.asp, line 134

I cannot find anywhere that NT AUTHORITY\IUSR is being told to attempt to log in. Im thinking it is some kind of default. I have googled every line of the error trying to find a resolve and have been basically flipping switches to try to find an answer, nothing i have tried provides any good results.

Is there a setting in the deep dark belly of windows that im not checking?

Comment: What is the compiler you're using? I ran into something similar with VS 2012 and ended up having to hack some files in the bowels of .Net Framework Directories (%systemroot%\Microsoft.Net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR' is used by IIS as the account for anonymous users. This means that IIS is using passing through the authentication information to the SQL server rather than using a specified user account.

In most situations you would either have specified an account to be used in the connection string or disabled anonymous access to ensure that the account passed through is a authenticated user account.

It is possible to give the IUSR account permissions on the SQL Server.

Try looking at this article as it may give you some assistance [The error "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'" in ASP.NET and SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269706/the-error-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-iusr-in-asp-net-and-sql-server)